# Does flask_json extension support top-level array JSON responses?

Tags: python, json, flask

I've been using flask_json's as_json decorators in my Flask API for a project. This has worked fine for json responses that are dicts/hashes at the top-level (`{name: ... }`) but I'd like to do a JSON response that is a list/array at the top-level:

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "02/07/2016 00:01:43", 
    ...
  },
  {
    "created_at": "02/07/2016 00:02:43", 
    ...
  }
]
```

When I tried to return an array, though, it raises a ValueError: "Unsupported return value" exception. And when I consult the module's [documentation](http://flask-json.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_json) it seems it only supports dict return values. It looks like all the example outputs for json_response() also produces hash JSONs. Does this mean I should use jsonify instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to 0.11, Flask's `jsonify` function only accepted dicts at the top level.  This was due to a security issue with very old versions of Internet Explorer that was open to attacks by overriding the `Array` prototype.

As of Flask 0.11, `jsonify` accepts any valid JSON value at the top level.

Flask-JSON allows the same types as `jsonify` as of [0.3.2](https://github.com/skozlovf/flask-json/issues/2).